# What Windows 8.1 (x64) / Linux SSD/HDD setup should I use?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have the following drives and their planned usage below.

120GB SSD - Arch Linux or Ubuntu (OS, programs)

240GB SSD - Windows (OS, programs)

1TB HDD - Split in half, one partition per OS (Documents, Pictures, Videos, Music, Paging files, search indexes, temp files, cache, logs)

- Is keeping the OS's completely separate with nothing shared the best option?
- Should I plan on using some sort of RAID configuration or spanning the drives?
- What is the best format for each drive/partition to be in?
- What should be moved to my HDD and linked if necessary?  My thoughts are the user directories, paging files, search indexes, temp files, cache and logs for windows and I'm unsure on linux.

Or... Is there just a much better option besides everything I mentioned?

**EDIT:: I would also be curious what would be the best setup if I set this system up strictly as a windows machine as I can use another computer for my linux developement or use a VM**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why the 2 different OSs? Are these on the same machine? Are you using virtualization? Have you considered backup?  
Sharing files between the systems could be very useful, especially for documents and media.

Comment: Linux will be my development machine.  Windows will be my normal use/gaming machine.  I was planning to dual boot both OS's rather than use virtualization.  I have not really put much thought into backup as I usually backup periodically manually to either cloud storage or external HDDs.  Do you think a 3 partition setup on the HDD would be best for shared docs/media keeping the paging/cache/etc for each operating system separate?

Comment: I have updated my question for answers concerning building the system without Linux.

Comment: You have a multi-part question that covers a broad range of material and are really asking for discussion/tutorial that goes way beyond the intended scope of a question.  Can you break this into a bunch of separate questions, each dealing with a single topic?

Comment: I think you should first narrow down your **desires** because there are numerous good possibilities and preferences here. The one thing I do recommend is to share that _media_ partition among your systems, regardless of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the future I would suggest being careful about the phrasing, using words like "best"
tends to create questions that are asking for an opinion, and as such are not a good fit
on any SE sites. However I will attempt to address consequences of various actions so you can
decide what is "best-for-you". I will provide a recommendation at the end, but again such
opinions are not a good fit on this site.

## Consequences:

> Is keeping the OS's completely separate with nothing shared the best option?

It will certainly make replacing an OS less complicated. Especially when it comes to
bootloaders. Of course that's only a benifit if you ever think you'll need to do so.

> Should I plan on using some sort of RAID configuration or spanning the drives?

Doing so will decrease the likely hood of native support via default drivers, this will make
creating backup/restore images of your operating systems more difficult, if you're the type
to do such things. For example, lets say you wish to make a .wim backup of your Windows installation
so you can restore it in the event of getting a virus, or having your OS corrputed. If you can't use
the default driver, then you'll need to build a WinPE disc that includes the required driver.

You have 2 drives so you can't create any kind of partity, and why mirror an ssd as they will
fail at the same time unless one has a longer re-write cycle life so you get no backup benefits from it.
 Sure you'll get a performance
boost from being able to read 2x faster, but you're already running from an SSD so read speeds
will already be blazing fast (unless you bought a terrible brand).

It will make the bootloader situation more complicated. If you use it as a spanned MBR drive then you will
end up with Arch's bootloader overwriting the Windows one, unless you chainload which would require manually
installing the Windows Bootloader to the VBR, and then manually adding an entry in Arch's bootloader for it.
If you use GPT they'll be in the same EFI System Partition. Either way it makes replacing an OS a bit more
difficult, though it does making booting them easier because you'll have all options present in a single
manager that boots by default. If you use the drives seperately then you can have each OS write to it's own
MBR, or in the case of GPT it's own ESP. You'll have to use your BIOS/UEFI's quick-boot menu to boot the OS
that's on the second hard drive :( , but each OS's bootloader is unaware of the other so replacing one OS is
much easier.

> What is the best format for each drive/partition to be in?

For Windows when you install it, it will automatically choose NTFS, and modern versions of Windows require it. As for
Arch I don't use Arch so I can't really comment on the various options available. I will note thought that EXT4 supports
TRIM. EXT4 has journal support to prevent data loss, but it can be disabled if you wish to decrease writes to the SSD.

> What should be moved to my HDD and linked if necessary? My thoughts are 
> the user directories, paging files, search indexes, temp files, cache 
> and logs for windows and I'm unsure on linux.

SSDs have a limited lifecycle so anything you can move off them an onto the hard drive will help make them
last longer. Of course such usage will wear out the hard drive sooner. Hard drives do not have a limited number
of writes, but they do wear out physically with use.

Storing your pagefile or swap partition on a hard drive will slow your system down since you are running the OS from
an SSD.

> I would also be curious what would be the best setup if I set this system up strictly as a 
> windows machine as I can use another computer for my linux developement or use a VM

Virtual machines do not get the same level of performance as physical machines. Unless you run a virtualizer that has
pci-passthrough you will be using an emulated graphics card which will further limit what you can run. Most virtualizers
do not support TRIM (used on ssds to aid life length) passthrough to the virtual machine's hard drive.

## Recommendation:

Best is a relative term, and only you can decide what is best. However if it were me I would keep the operating
systems each on their own drive with their own bootloaders, and just use the quick-boot menu on your PC to get to them.
That is assuming your computer has one (likely does). You have 2 drives, so why not take advantage of that.

Unless you have very little ram, don't use a pagefile or swap partition. It will wear out the drive sooner, and since copying files is so fast from an ssd you can afford to constantly flush files out of memory to make room for new ones. If you don't have enough memory, then make the swap partition/page files on their OS SSD; running it from the hard drive will create a bottleneck. The whole point of having an SSD is to make it quicker to copy files from the source to the memory, this ends up waisted if your virtual memory is stored on a slower device.

I would use EXT4 for Arch, but only because I'm not familiar with some of the other options available to it, if you are then maybe there's a better option. Use NTFS for Windows, and use NTFS for the hard drive because you'll want a filesystem that can be accessed
from both operating systems, has support for journaling, supports long filenames, and supports files larger than 4 gigabytes.

I wouldn't bother redirecting logs, or user folders to the hard drive. SSD's may have a limited life-cycle but it's not overly short so
why go through the trouble of redirecting logs, and etc. As for the user data, why redirect those folders either. Just don't
use them; same for Arch. Instead create your own folders on the hard drive. Integrating
things just makes it a pain if you ever need to un-integrate them.